# Search results with autocompletion

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm building an app in swift requiring to be able to search cities and I would like the search to work with autocompletion. I want to do something like if user types any character or word in the searchbox, it fetches the result from mysql database that starts from that character or word and shows the result in auto suggestion or auto complete. my backend service is ready.. The only problem is I don't know how I can implement this feature. At The moment what my code is doing is when user types something in the search bar, he clicks the search button in the keyboard and then results come. hope you will understand what I am saying. Here is my current code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mySearchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
   var dict = NSDictionary()
    var searchResults = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return searchResults.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
       let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

        myCell.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]

        return myCell

    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
         if(searchBar.text!.isEmpty)
         {
            return
         }

        doSearch(searchBar.text!)

    }



    func doSearch(searchWord: String)

    {

      mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/myproject")
         let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);

        let params = ["city" : searchWord]
        do {

            let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)



            request.HTTPBody = data


        } catch {
            //handle error. Probably return or mark function as throws
            print("error is \(error)")
            //return
        }


        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";



        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response: NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            if error != nil
            {
                // display an alert message
                self.displayAlertMessage(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
              let json: NSDictionary?
         do {
            json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            self.searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            self.myTableView.reloadData()

            if let parseJSON = json {
              print(parseJSON)

               // var index = 0
                self.dict = parseJSON
              print("count is \(self.dict.count)")
                for var i = 0; i < self.dict.count - 1; i++ {
                    let cityname = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["City"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
                   self.searchResults.append(cityname)
                }



                        self.myTableView.reloadData()


            }

            } catch {
                print(error);
            }

            }


            })


        task.resume()

    }


    func displayAlertMessage(userMessage: String)
    {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        let okAction =  UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(okAction);
        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        mySearchBar.text = ""
        mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }




}
```

Comment: I don't really have an answer, but have you looked at this tutorial from Ray Wenderlich: http://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial . In there they use the `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol that have this method: `updateSearchResultsForSearchController:` which - as it says in the documentation - is: "Called when the search bar becomes the first responder or when the user makes changes inside the search bar." Maybe that will help you

Comment: @pbodsk Okay I'll check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I have successfully implemented a search. Here is my code

```
class  CityTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var dict = NSDictionary()
    var filterTableData = [String]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()


    var newTableData = [String]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        self.resultSearchController = ({

            let controller  = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            return controller


        })()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        if(self.resultSearchController.active){

            return self.filterTableData.count
        }else {

            return dict.count
        }



    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CountryTableViewCell

        if(self.resultSearchController.active){

            cell.cityNameLabel.text = filterTableData[indexPath.row]
            return cell

        }else{

            cell.cityNameLabel.text = (((self.dict["\(indexPath.row)"] as?NSDictionary)!["City"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
            return cell
        }



    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        let searchWord = searchController.searchBar.text!

        getCityNamesFromServer(searchWord)

        let searchPredict = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        print("searchPredict is \(searchController.searchBar.text!)")

        for var i = 0; i < self.dict.count; i++ {
            let cityname = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["City"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
        newTableData.append(cityname)
        }

        let array = (newTableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredict)
        print("array is\(array)")
        filterTableData = array as! [String]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }






    func getCityNamesFromServer(searchWord:String){


        let url:String = "http://localhost/"
        let params = ["city":searchWord]



        ServerRequest.postToServer(url, params: params) { result, error in

            if let result = result {
                print(result)

                self.dict = result

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one technique:

- Make your ViewController a delegate to your search Bar text field.
- Implement the delegate -
- searchBar:textDidChange:
- Implement a method say 'UpdateResults'  This method should be doing these-

  a. Check if searchBar has changed, in that case set the searchResults
  to nil (Make a instance var searchResults that is optional array.

  b. Perform your network operation to fetch results asynchronously (as
  you already do).

  c. When you receive results, append them to the searchResults (by
  creating it if it is nil)

  d. Once all search results are appended, dispatch on main thread, and
  make the relevant results table to reload.

Comment: I am newbie is it possible that you can write some code here